# How do you create a .NET program using the new CSPROJ format in VS2017 (Or VS2019)

Tags: .net, visual-studio

There's some great tools for converting the old CSPROJ format to the new CSPROJ format, such as [this one](https://github.com/hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017).  The new format supports things like direct references to NuGet packages and other cool stuff.

However, how do you create a brand new project in Visual Studio 2017 or Visual Studio 2019?  If I create a .NET library project:

[image]

Then this project is created in the old format and has to be upgraded using the tool again.  Can anyone shed some light on what projects support the new format vs. the old format?

Comment: You can use .NET Core or .NET Standard library project to get all advantages of new sdk-style projects

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The new CSPROJ is used by .NET Core and automatically created when creating new .NET Core project.

The trick that I have uses to to create a new style .NET Framework under Rider is (as suggested by a colleague):

1. create a .NET Core project
2. switch it to a .NET Framework

I think that this works only under VS.

Comment: Ah gotcha, so even though ".NET Framework (Full)" works with the new CSPROJ format, there's no template to create it directly.  You have to create a .NET Core or .NET Standard project and then convert it to target the other runtime.

Comment: I think that you're right. However: in a talk I've been some time ago, the difference between the two csproj types has been explained and I recall that there are some cases where the new csproj doesn't work with .NET framework. If I find out more in my notes I'll edit the answer

Comment: I have an extension with sdk style .net framework project templates. Might be useful https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rubberduckdev.SDKStyleTemplatesNet